# Visual Studio Command Prompt not working properly

Tags: command, prompt

When I press shift+F5, no command prompt shows up even though I'm told that's what is supposed to happen. Instead, the prompt flickers and then disappears almost instantly. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

printf("Wednesday!\n\a\a\a\a"); //printf() is a function

return 15;

}
```

I have no idea what to do, and couldn't find an explanation anywhere else.

Comment: Found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068565/printf-is-not-printing-anything-to-output-c-sdl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printf is not printing anything to output? C++ SDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068565/printf-is-not-printing-anything-to-output-c-sdl)